# Find UIButton in Tableview header and change button title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have two-section headers and each header has UIButton, When I tap that UIButtons in header one popup will be opened. It has two buttons YES and NO. When user clicked the YES option in that popup I want to show YES title in the Header button. 
Ex: If the user tapped on Section 1 header button popup will be opened and the selected Yes. I want to display that Y$S text in my Section 1 header button tile.

My code :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section == 0) {

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];
         view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

         UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, tableView.frame.size.width-40, 21)];
         label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

         label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFontLight size:12];
         label.textColor = [UIColor LSBlackColor];
         NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(@"Button1", nil);
         label.text = string;
         UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 48, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
         line.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
 operate = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width - 100, 6, 100, 30)];
 [operate setTitle:@"Button1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [operate setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 65/255.0 green: 190/255.0 blue: 236/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 operate.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFontRegular size:14];
 operate.tag = 10;
 [operate addTarget:self action:@selector(operateAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         [view addSubview:label];
         [view addSubview:line];
         [view addSubview:operate];
         return view;
}
else if (section == 1) {
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40)];
         view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

         UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, tableView.frame.size.width-40, 21)];
         label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

         label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFontLight size:12];
         label.textColor = [UIColor LSBlackColor];
         NSString *string = NSLocalizedString(@"Button1", nil);
         label.text = string;
 UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 48, tableView.frame.size.width, 1)];
    line.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    operateandEdit = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.size.width - 120, 6, 100, 30)];
    [operateandEdit setTitle:@"Button2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [operateandEdit setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 65/255.0 green: 190/255.0 blue: 236/255.0 alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    operateandEdit.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:kAppFontRegular size:14];
    operateandEdit.tag = 11;
    [operateandEdit addTarget:self action:@selector(operateAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

         [view addSubview:label];
         [view addSubview:line];
         [view addSubview:operateandEdit];
         return view;
}
return nil;
}
```

In operation action:

```
-(void) operateAction:(id) sender {
if (operate.tag == 10) {
    if (sender.tag == 5) {
        [operate setTitle:@"YES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [operate setTitle:@"NO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
} else {
    if (sender.tag == 5) {
        [operateandEdit setTitle:@"YES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [operateandEdit setTitle:@"NO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
[self cancelButtonClicked:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", sender.currentTitle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look: your `operate.tag` will always be 10 and condition will always be `true` so never go into else block.

Check the following code, here you have to take a different tag for all four buttons and then use it.

```
if (sender.tag == 5) {
    [operate setTitle:@"YES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if (sender.tag == 6) {
    [operate setTitle:@"NO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else if (sender.tag == 7) {
    [operateandEdit setTitle:@"YES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [operateandEdit setTitle:@"NO" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift change button title like this

```
yourButton.setTitle("Yes", for: .normal)
```